# failed to run msbuild while installing dlib

Tags: python

I tried to install dlib: `python install dlib`

 
cmake installed using : `python install cmake` (cmake path also set as system var) 

visual studio 14 2015 has been installed in my system. 

The system is: Windows - 6.1.7601 - AMD64

```
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\personal\study material\python\python.

  -- Building for: Visual Studio 14 2015
  CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:    
Failed to run MSBuild command:

      C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe

    to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

      Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
      Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

      Build started 02-08-2019 14:37:03.
      Project "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xqz7oflh\dlib\bu
ild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.14.4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" on node
1 (default targets).
      C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xqz7oflh\dlib\build\temp.
win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.14.4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj(14,2): error MSB40
19: The imported project "C:\Personal\Study Material\Python\dlib-19.6\build\CMak
eFiles\3.14.4\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path
in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
      Done Building Project "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xq
z7oflh\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.14.4\VCTargetsPath.vcx
proj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

      Build FAILED.

      "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xqz7oflh\dlib\build\temp
.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.14.4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default target)
 (1) ->
        C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xqz7oflh\dlib\build\tem
p.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.14.4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj(14,2): error MSB
4019: The imported project "C:\Personal\Study Material\Python\dlib-19.6\build\CM
akeFiles\3.14.4\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the pat
h in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

          0 Warning(s)
          1 Error(s)

      Time Elapsed 00:00:00.28


    Exit code: 1



  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-xqz7oflh/dlib/build
/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: It would be great if you give us a little explanation (environment, procedure) and not just post your error.

Comment: I tried to install dlib: python install dlib
cmake installed using : python install cmake (cmake path also set as system var) visual studio 14 2015 has been installed in my system. The system is: Windows - 6.1.7601 - AMD64

Comment: You can [edit] your question and add informations there